# Perforce SQL return file name without path appended to beginning

Tags: sql, string, perforce

I am using perforce.  Some helpful members of the stackoverflow community helped me find the p4reports program that sets up an ODBC data source to access our perforce data.  I created a query that returns exactly the information i need ... *almost*.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT a.file, a.time, a.action, a.revision, a.change, b.description
FROM files a, changes b
WHERE a.change = b.change AND ((b.p4options='longdesc'));
```

The problem is that the a.file column returns the name of the file with the whole path, like this:

```
//depot/folder_1/folder_2/.../file_name.txt
```

I would like this column to just contain the file name, like this:

```
file_name.txt
```

Does anyone know an SQL query that could do this? Now matter how deeply nested a file is in a folder structure?

Here is a link to the perforce SQL report functions.  Some basic string functions but I am having a hard time putting together how I can always return the right text with these functions.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4report/ab_functions.html#1045728

In MySQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT right(a.file,locate("/",reverse(a.file))-1), a.time, a.action, a.revision, a.change, b.description
FROM files a, changes b
WHERE a.change = b.change AND ((b.p4options='longdesc'));
```

And it would work, but there is no `reverse` function in the perforce SQL as far as I can tell.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: P4Report and its database is SQL-92 compliant. SQL-92 doesn't have any function for string reversing. p4-randall's suggestion might be the way for you to go in this case, unless you can do the conversion in your report/output layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at P4toDB, which will replicate Perforce data into a regular database.  That way you can run more advanced SQL queries or even use a report engine.

http://kb.perforce.com/article/1172/p4todb-readme

Comment: how quickly does changes to Perforce metadata replicate to the SQL database? i.e. if I submit a changelist, how soon after can I query the database about the change?

Comment: yeah good question, I have not tried this yet, but the link supplied here has a lot of good information, check it out!

Comment: I did read the article first; there is no clear answer so I asked the above question.

Comment: There's a property called <code>FETCH_DELAY</code> in the configuration file, and I believe it defaults to 5 seconds.  See http://kb.perforce.com/article/1453/p4todb-getting-started.